# How can I find the height of $ABCD?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, euclidean-geometry, area

[image]

I found these values:

> $$\frac{ah}{2}=14$$
>
> $$\frac {a+b}{2}×h=23$$
>
> Finally, I found $ah=28$, $bh=18$, $a=\frac{14b}{9}$.
>
> Here, $a//b$ and $S$ is area.

Now, what should I do?

Comment: what else is given?

Comment: I have no other information.

Comment: @Math with no more information the solution is $$h=\frac{46}{a+b}$$ with  $$\frac{a}b=\frac{14}{9}$$

Comment: There's not enough information to solve this problem.

Comment: You did not define $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Here, $a//b$ parallel sides.

Comment: @Dylan I understood. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct, all what you can find by the givens is that

$$h=\frac{46}{a+b}$$

and also that

$$\frac{ah}{2}=14 \quad \frac{bh}{2}=9 \implies \frac ab=\frac{14}{9}$$

Since we have three unknowns and 2 equations to solve completely we need some other infomation.

Comment: What is value $h$? Thank you.

Comment: There are infinitely many values for example for a=14 and b=9 we obtain h=2 but for a=28 and b=18 we obtain h=1.

Answer (score 1):

I think some information is missing in this question. What you have done up to there is completely fine but you need one more equation to solve the system. At this point, we can have $a = 14$, $b = 9$ and $h = 2$. But we also can have $a = 28$, $b = 18$ and $h = 1$. So we can't have an exact value for $h$ with the given information.

However, if question asks $h$ with respect to $a$ and $b$, as you have already found, it is
$$h = \frac{46}{a+b}$$